# Is the IKSlideshowModeQuickLook mode of IKSlideshow gone?

Tags: cocoa, core-image

In the class `IKSlideshow`, there is a method named `–runSlideshowWithDataSource:inMode:options:`

For the argument `slideshowMode`, The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKSlideShow/IKSlideshow_Reference.html) says:

> A constant that indicate what kind of items are in the slideshow — `IKSlideshowModeImages`, `IKSlideshowModePDF`, or `IKSlideshowModeQuickLook`. See “[Slideshow Modes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKSlideShow/IKSlideshow_Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Slideshow_Modes)”.

Following the link, the mode `IKSlideshowModeQuickLook` seems to be gone. There is only three modes (IKSlideshowModeImages, IKSlideshowModePDF, IKSlideshowModeOther).

This constant seems to be defined nowhere now.
At least, it's not in:

> /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IKImageBrowserView.h
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IKImageBrowserView.h
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IKImageBrowserView.h

Am I missing a header to import, or is this mode gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using a `IKImageBrowserView` view, all I needed to do was to implement the following method, and ask for QLPreviewPanel to come front:

```
- (void) imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *) aBrowser cellWasDoubleClickedAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

I assume that the IKSlideshowModeQuickLook mode is gone, and that the updater of the documentation missed this occurrence. Let me know if you find otherwise.